# import error that doesn't replicate in different clones of the same repository

Tags: python, importerror, git-clone

I have a big python project. When I try to execute a certain script I get an import error
something like:

```
    from my_package import xyz
ImportError: cannot import name 'xyz'
```

Where my_package is an existing directory in the code base, and xyz.py is within this directory. Yes, I checked, and this directory is in the search path.

What really boggles my mind is that on a different machine, when I clone the same repository, activate the same virtual environment, and try the exact same script - I don't get this error.

I try to figure what is wrong and how to fix it, and the fact that it happens on a remote server, and does not replicate on my own computer just seem weird.

Any clue what could go wrong and where should I look for the bug?

EDIT: some additional information -

When I ran the script as it should i.e.

```
python ./myscript.py
```

It gives the above error. But when I run the problematic import command within the interpreter:

> python
>
> > > from my_package import xyz

I get no error whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The three potential errors I can think of are the following:

- Does the git project use submodules? If so, you need to make sure you run a `git clone` with the `--recursive` flag, since it might not have downloaded all the submodules correctly.
- How are you setting up the virtual environments? Usually they shouldn't be stored within the git repository, but should instead be created on each machine. The dependencies can then be installed from the project's `requirements.txt` file. Sharing the same virtual environment between multiple machines could mean that it doesn't behave correctly on one of them.
- Have you compared the versions of Python used between both machines. If it's a built-in module that's failing to import then perhaps your second machine isn't using a new enough version of Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the actual files on both machines and they look identical. I did set up the environment using the requirements.txt, and I use the same python version

Comment: Ok in that case, it could be that you're missing an `__init__.py` in the submodule? Without one of those, Python considers the folder to be a folder with code in it rather than a Python package.

Comment: nope. the init file exists in both clones.

Comment: Wow that is very strange. Have a glance at your `sys.path` in both cases - there might be some differences which might be causing the problem

Comment: sys.path is different of course, as the directory structure is different in those systems, but in both cases it contains the project's root directory, relative to which all the packages are located.

Comment: So you're sure they're being run from the same directory

Comment: as far as I can tell. I runthe script from the command line, and I change the directory to the project root before I run the script. the type "python ./myscript.py". I print the sys.path as the first command, and see that it contains the project root, which is also the current directory. unless I'm doing something wrong here, I'm pretty sure everything should be the same

Comment: Yeah that should work - I think I'm stumped. Sorry I don't think I can help more than that.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts